# ASP.NET MVC error 403 forbidden Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, owin, http-status-code-403

I follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp) from Microsoft to add Microsoft sign in into my project - ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2.

I managed login into my Microsoft account access the main page. However, when I tried to logout and re-login again, instead of reaching the main page, it throws 403 forbidden Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2. I tried to delete the history and close the page, and able to login, but when I tried the 2nd attempt I will get the same error again.

I checked the cookies history and seems like this cookie `.AspNet.Cookies` is causing the problem. When I tried to remove `.AspNet.Cookies`, I'm able to access the page without any error.

[image]

I tried to implement `SameSiteCookieManager` class from this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/owin-samesite) and added into my `startup.cs` with hopes that it will help, but I have no luck with that.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Home/Login"),
        CookieSameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax,
        CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
    });
}
```

Can anyone pointed out what is the issue here? I have been struggling with this for almost 2 weeks. Really appreciate any kind of help here.

Answer (score 0):

> ASP.NET MVC error 403 forbidden Microsoft-Azure-Application-Gateway/v2

- I have followed the given document and able to login , logout and re-login again without any issues, ***by changing few settings in `Azure Active Directory`***
- Navigate to ***Azure Portal*** => ***Azure Active Director***y => Your ***Registered App*** => ***Authentication*** => ***Add Platform***
- Click on the ***Add Paltform*** => Select **Web**  =>  Add ***Redirect URIs*** and  ***Front-channel logout URL***
- Under  ***Implicit grant and hybrid flows***,make sure ***ID tokens*** checkbox is selected => ***Configure***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm using my existing platform, Mobile and desktop applications. Could it be the issue? for the logout URL is it a must? Do you implement the SameSite cookie as well for this?

Comment: I have not implemented SameSite cookie.Followed only the 1st document. Yes logout URL is a must. Have you tried with that?

Comment: I haven't tried to add the logout URL, as I'm using the existing Mobile & Desktop application platform. Can I check, will there be any impact to the existing application if I add the logout URL to it? will the application logout URL direct to the same URL?

Comment: Haven't checked yet, need to verify that

Comment: Hi @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT, I've followed your method to add the logout URL. I'm able to logout and login multiple times. However, I still encountered the 403 Forbidden Microsoft Gateway. I think I had the same issue with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906669/azure-front-door-waf-is-blocking-aspnet-applicationcookie There are 2 dashes (--) in my cookies, and it seems like my WAF is blocking it. I tried to off the rule 942440, and it works with no issue. However, I wish to not make any changes to the rule. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Would it be possible to not using cookies for this login?

Comment: AFAIK disabling the firewall is the current option available to resolve the issue.

Comment: will there be any negative impact if this rule is off?

Comment: Instead of disabling the entire Firewall, Just disable/remove the rule which is blocking your Request

Comment: I'm not sure if this solution consider good or not. I added 2 custom exclusion rules to exclude 2 cookies: AspNet.Cookies and OpenIdConnect.nonce. It seems to work for my case.